# ¿Como contabilizar los distintos valores de un mismo campo?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

muy buen día.

Lo que requiero es poder contabilizar los resultados de un mismo campo y saber cuantos registros de "activos" e "inactivos" tiene un registro, es decir, buscando el destino "Riviera Maya" se que cuenta con 150 registros activos y con 98 inactivos.

He intentado la siguiente consulta mas no logro definirla correctamente:

```
SELECT M.idMarket,
    M.name marketName,
    M.active marketStatus,
    M.CountryA2,
    (
        SELECT count(h.active)
        FROM hotels
        WHERE h.active = 1
        ) AS hoteles_activos,
    (
        SELECT count(active)
        FROM hotels
        WHERE active = 0
        ) AS hoteles_inactivos
FROM markets M
JOIN hotels H ON H.IdMarket = M.IdMarket
GROUP BY M.idmarket,
    M.name,
    M.active,
    M.CountryA2
```

y el resultado no es el esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano agradezco mucho su apoyo.

Slds!

Comment: ¿Con registro activo te refieres al markerstatus? ¿O simplemente a hoteles_activos,? Gracias y bienvenido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema principal es que no estás relacionando las subconsultas con la consulta principal. Pero aun corrigiendo eso, es un proceso poco eficiente porque se hacen lecturas adicionales a las tablas. Todo puede hacerse en un simple `SELECT` usando un agregado condicional.

```
SELECT M.idMarket,
    M.name marketName,
    M.active marketStatus,
    M.CountryA2,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN h.active = 1 THEN 1 END) AS hoteles_activos,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN h.active = 0 THEN 1 END) AS hoteles_inactivos
FROM markets M
JOIN hotels H ON H.IdMarket = M.IdMarket
GROUP BY M.idmarket,
    M.name,
    M.active,
    M.CountryA2;
```

Así queda una consulta más sencilla y gracias al formato también se facilita su lectura.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, entiendo cual fue mi problema y la manera de la resolución. Te agradezco mi estimado!!